# Pinescript delta between market close previous day and close after first 30 minutes at actual day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I struggle with pinescript as it says the timeframe is unsupported.

```
// Close der 9:00 Uhr Kerze
nine_am_close = request.security("INDEX:DAX", "30", close[0])

// Berechnung der Gap-Größe
previous_close = request.security("INDEX:DAX", "D", close[1])
gap_size = nine_am_close - previous_close
```

I try to caculate the gap at close of  9:00 bar.
Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is the symbol. The future FDAX works.